# Reference to stackoverflow profile in CV

Tags: cv

Is there stackoverflow's logo in some packages?

[image]

Comment: Add the logo as a picture.

Comment: Yes, but I had some problem to align name with logo, logo stands a bit higher than text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far I've been able to do is to use `fontawesome` package and color it;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks   = true, 
    urlcolor     = darkgray
}

\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FDA333}
\definecolor{materialorange}{HTML}{FF5722}

\begin{document}

    \huge \textnormal{\textcolor{materialorange}{\faStackOverflow}} 
    \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/105647/hamidreza}{Hamidreza}\\

    \huge \textnormal{\textcolor{orange}{\faStackOverflow}} 
    \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/105647/hamidreza}{Hamidreza} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but I wondered if there is something in original color ( gray and orange).

Comment: It's possible to add credit of stackoverflow and math.stackexchange to CV in Latex?

Comment: I think you can handle it the best with image of the score box.

Comment: Image? It's not a good idea. I want to add my score automatically be latex not add an image

Comment: If you are talking about a CV in a web page you can use their APIs.

Comment: It's possible to tell more details? I try to add this option to my CV in latex but after some tries, I failed.